# Fix missing provider in production

Tags: javascript, vue.js, solidity, web3js, ethers.js

The function getAllTickets is calling the contract as a provider.

The issue is that, when running the application in localHost this function works fine and the contract method "getAllTickets" gets called.

But when running the application in production (real domain) I get the error

> Uncaught Error: missing provider (argument="provider", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=providers/5.5.3)

```
async getAllTickets({commit}) {
    try {
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
      const ticketsContract = new ethers.Contract(ticketsContractAddress, ticketsAbi, provider)
      const allTicketsHash = await ticketsContract.getAllTickets()
      const parcedTickets = allTicketsHash.map((ticket) => ({
        ticketOwner: ticket.ticket_owner,
        timestamp: new Date(ticket.timestamp.toNumber() * 1000).toLocaleString(),
        keyword: ticket.keyword,
        amount: parseInt(ticket.amount._hex) / (10 ** 18)
      }))
      commit('setAllTickets', parcedTickets)
      
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  },
}
```

What would be the correct way of handling this contract method as a provider in production enviroment?

I want to be able a user to be able call this function without having connected a wallet.

Comment: I don't know if this would help, but you could try some of these things: try to console.log the `provider` variable in both dev and prod. Also when you said that it works in localhost, is it in dev server mode? or have you tried it in production mode but in localhost? if you have, is the localhost production mode working or not?

Answer (score 0):

I have some simple index.js, use Provider JsonRPCPRovider without Metamask.

```js
const url = 'https://polygon-rpc.com'; 
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(url);
const signer = provider.getSigner('0x2791Bca1f2de4661ED88A30C99A7a9449Aa84174');
```

Comment: Hi Kaoos, please add the last two lines inside a code block to make it easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

using a different browser and a different wallet, helped me resolve the issue.